# get_absolute_url в связанных моделях или sitemap.xml со связью ManyToMany

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте.

Есть необходимость иметь доступным экземпляр модели на разных урлах. 
К примеру, чтобы группа товаров была доступна во всех городах.

Для наглядности:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    cities = models.ManyToManyField(City)
```

Городов, скажем, 30, а товаров 150. Если я выберу все товары, то получу 150 объектов, если все 30 городов, то 30 объектов.

Синтетически урл делаю таким, чтобы он принимал город, и товар:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<city>[\w.@+-]+)/(?P<product>[\w.@+-]+)/$',
        view=views.CityProductView.as_view(),
        name='city_product'
    )
]
```

Во вьюхе же, что-то вроде этого:

```
class ProductCity(DetailView):
    model = Product

    def get_object(self):
        product = get_object_or_404(Product city__name__iexact=self.kwargs['city'])
        return service
```

И по факту, становится доступно 30 * 150 страниц на самом сайте, что и требовалось.

Вопрос:

Как все эти урлы отдать в `sitemap` ?

Точно этот же вопрос встал, при необходимости генерить `sitemap` под `GET` параметры страницы (фильтры).

Если метод `items` можно сделать как-то вроде:

```
def items(self):
    items = []
    cities = City.objects.all()
    for city in cities:
        products = Product.objects.filter(cities__in=[city])
        items.extend(products)
    return items
```

То что делать с `location`, который должен возвращать `get_absolute_url()` ?

Как делают на досках объявлений, чтобы все категории были были в каждом из города ? 
Не совсем понимаю логику.

Я привык писать к моделям get_absolute_url() и писать для этого метода тесты, а как быть в этом случае ?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такое рабочее решение:

В модели создаётся метод, например `get_sitemap_urls`:

```
def get_sitemap_urls(self):
    return [reverse('products:city_product', args=[i.name, self.slug]) for i in self.cities.all()]
```

т.е. фактически генерим список, исходя из всех, в данном случае, городов, с которыми связана модель.

А затем в `sitemap.py` изменяем метод `items` и `location`

```
def items(self):
    return list(
         itertools.chain.from_iterable(( object.get_sitemap_urls()
                                         for object in 
                                         Product.objects.all()))
    )

def location(self, item):
    return item
```

К сожалению, пока что не придумал, как оставить в живых метод `lastmod`